# Text to speech and accompanying metadata

Tags: speech-synthesis

I want to convert text to speech and be supplied with the accompanying meta data as to what interval each word occurs at and its period. So "The dog ate" might be

The: start 0, end .3s
Dog: start .5s, end .8s
Ate: start .11s, end .14s

Is there way of convert text to speech and has obtaining such data other than going through the resulting audio file looking for pauses. 
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

iSpeech offer a txt to speech solution whose api is able to provide position markers for words which is excellent. The info can be found in section four of the api which can be found here http://www.ispeech.org/api . Would like to hear of other sollutions though. 
Cheers

Comment: Just looked at there pricing. Not too brilliant. Theres got to be an opensource sollution